# Unremovable partition

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a Asus eee pc netbook with an ssd drive.   The drive has 2 partitions, 3.9gb and 15gb.
I have tried merging them in to 1 partition, tried deleting the partitions, and tried to format the ssd thing. Nothing works.

All I want is to have 1 partition utilizing all the free disk space.

Can anybody please help....?

Mike

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you tried and what happened (not).

Comment: are you running the partition editor on one of the partitions you want to delete?

Answer (score 0):

GPartEd will do it for you. If something is locked, usually booting from a different system (i.e. a Live CD) will prevent it from being locked by the Operating System

Answer (score 0):

The earliest models such as the 701 had two physical SSD drives, typically 4GB and 16GB, so you cannot merge them at the partition level. Under XP your best option is to mount the larger drive as a folder on the smaller (system) file system.